# Service Bus Notification Hub: What is the payload size limit for the push notification?

Tags: azure, notifications

As far as I know Apple limits push notification payload by 256 bytes, Windows Phone limits it by 3KB. 
Does Azure Notification Hub provide some workaround for this limitations?
What is expected behavior of the Notification Hub if a notification is sent to an Apple device and its payload is longer then 256 bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a Program Manager on the Notification Hub feature.
Notification Hubs do not provide any workaround to the size limitations of the various platform notification systems.

When sending a notification to template registrations, when applying the template results in a notification that is too large, you will see it rejected by the PNS and the Notification Hub will report the error in the portal dashboard as 'Payload errors'.

When sending a native message, the send request will fail and you will get the status code "Request entity too large".