# Azure Notification Hub Max payload length

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

Is there any documentation where I can find how notification hub keep consistency over all platforms for payload length?

I mean that:

> In iOS 8 and later, the maximum size allowed for a notification
>   payload is 2 kilobytes; Apple Push Notification service refuses any
>   notification that exceeds this limit. (Prior to iOS 8 and in OS X, the
>   maximum payload size is 256 bytes.)

So what will be if I will send notification that meet to last iOs requirements but doesn't meet to old version of iOs and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144541/service-bus-notification-hub-what-is-the-payload-size-limit-for-the-push-notifi) The Notification Hub does not know whether a given push token is for a device with iOS 7 or iOS 8. So it will send the notification along to Apple and report an error in the Notification Hub dashboard if Apple returns an error.

So to take advantage of the longer payloads, you need to keep track of which of your users' devices have iOS 8.x.

Comment: Yes, I had the same understanding. 
Thanks.